# Just need some help regarding a calculator C#

Tags: c#

I am making a calculator to gain some experience with C#, atm i have one textbox ontop of one another, the lower one is called calculation; i want this one to show the sum being calculated. The text box on top is called result and i obviously want that to display the result; the result box works fine. I want the lower text box ( called calculation ) to display the + symbol which it wont let me do and at the moment i am only able to show the digits. I assume this is a data type problem. Any help/advice? thank you! (I'm sorting this out before moving onto the other symbols and eventually putting it into a switch case :) )

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    public Form1()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
    }

    double num1 = 0;
    double num2 = 0;

    private void Clearbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Calculation.Clear();
        Result.Clear();
    }

    private void Numericclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = (Button)sender;
        Calculation.Text = Calculation.Text + button.Text;
    }

    private void Plusbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        num1 = num1 + double.Parse(Calculation.Text);
        Result.Show();
    }

    private void Equalsbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        num2 = num1 + double.Parse(Calculation.Text);
        Result.Text = num2.ToString();
        num1 = 0;

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If you use the (+) operator with strings it concatenates them together.

This line `Calculation.Text = Calculation.Text + button.Text;`

In C# 6 will be this:

```
Calculation.Text = $"{Calculation.Text} + {button.Text}";
```

Lower than C# 6:

```
Calculation.Text = string.Format("{0} + {1}", Calculation.Text, button.Text);
```

String Concatenation Documentation: [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228504.aspx)

Example of difference between the operand + and as a string "+":

```
//+ operand concats string
var text = "abc";
var text2 = "def";

var result = text + text2;
//result -> "abcdef"

var result2 = text + "+" + text2;
//result -> "abc+def"
```

Comment: Thanks, Is there any other way of going about it? perhaps a less complex since i'm a novice?

Comment: This isn't complex. You need the plus as a string so you it has to be in the format of "+" otherwise it will get treated as an operand. Manipulating strings is far more basic than using events and textboxes and forms. Maybe you should take a step back to just a console app.

Comment: i'll give it a shot but i'm a bit uncertain and i can't really take a step back since I'm using them for Uni, but thanks for the advice

Comment: Uni as in University?

Comment: UPDATE: i have got it to work with this code however when i click plus two '+' are entered rather than one, how do i go about this?

Comment: I can update answer with some more examples and one more way of concatenating strings.

Comment: That's because you are using Calculation.Text. It is going to add it's self to the button.Text every time

Comment: ahhh, okay i understand that; so how would i go about this?

Comment: What is it you are trying to do with the NumericClick event?

Comment: I created the numericClick to add the button clicked into the calculation text box ready for calculation

Comment: So you just want to display the current operand of the calculator. So if I press plus display a plus, if I press - display the -. But always a single operand?

Comment: yeah you've got it! so if i clicked 4 * 4 that would be displayed in the lower text box called calculation and then obviously when the equals is clicked it is computed to the answer in the results text box - been trying all day but im stumped! appreciate the help

Comment: So these are going to build up? I can doing 4 + 5 - 7 * 9? Etc.

Comment: That is was i'm hoping to do eventually but this isn't a priority right now

Comment: if this is not possible however i do not mind sticking to just two numbers at a time

Comment: I cannot reply as i do not have a high enough reputation

Comment: Oh weird. Didn't know that was a thing.

Comment: Okay how about this. I technically answered your question about how to display the + as a string. So this quesiton is closed.

You can review this calculator example by microsoft: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Simple-Calculator-54ec8e4a and if you have more questions reopen a new question.